# How to install gmagick php extension on windows

Tags: php, windows, apache

Anyone has done a successful gmagick php install on windows? how?

I have been trying with this:

```
https://pecl.php.net/package/gmagick/1.1.6RC1/windows
```

and this

```
https://pecl.php.net/package/gmagick/1.1.3RC1/windows
```

graphicsmagick:

```
GraphicsMagick-1.3.21-Q16-win32-dll.exe
```

and environment variable MAGICK_HOME pointing to the dlls from pecl.php.net

- windows 7 sp1 x64
- apache 2.4.4 and 2.4.9
- php 5.5.0 and 5.5.23
- I'm using x86 TS php

The moment I enable the extension and restart apache, apache just keeps restarting:

```
[Fri Apr 03 19:33:42.889022 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5868:tid 416]
AH00428: Parent: child process 5700 exited with status 3221225725 --
Restarting.
```

I'm already using this on apache

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
   ThreadStackSize 8388608
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Make sure your DLL is compiled for PHP 5.5 and not another version

Comment: @Machavity That's a good tip, but I already checked many times on both gmagick versions tested.